# Not able to installl Ubuntu on my ASUS laptop

Tags: playonlinux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-headers

I am trying to install ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 from a bootable 8GB USB  in my new ASUS laptop (8gb ram, 512 SSD) and have partitioned the SSD into 2 partitiona and left 70 GB unallocated.

I have tried installing Ubuntu by various ways I have tried by disabling secure boot and disabling fast boot, but every time it shows that needs 8.6 GB of memory but your computer has only 7.8 GB of free space. Please tell me how can I install Ubuntu alongside Windows

Comment: You should not partition from Windows other than shrinking the NTFS partition and rebooting so it can run chkdsk. Make sure Windows fast start up is off. And then Ubuntu should install into unallocated space. Ubuntu cannot use a NTFS partition.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Did you boot from the LiveUSB with Ubuntu on it to create a dual boot system http://opensource.com/article/18/5/dual-boot-linux , or are you trying to install it into Windows Subsystem for Linux? WSL can only install Linux versions from the Microsoft Store: See http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10  Please click [edit] and let us know what you are trying to do, for playonlinux and WSL are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **:-)** When you boot the Ubuntu USB and you go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and execute `sudo lshw -class disk -class storage` what to you get?  Please [edit] your question to provide this valuable info and then leave a comment @Fabby so I can review....